# Optimal number of additional classes and activities for a 4-year-old

Tags: pre-schooler, development

I have two daughters, 4 and 2 years old. Since the older one is pretty organized, we start considering various additional activities on top of regular childcare e.g. music, dances, gymnastics, just name it.

How much time is optimal to invest into these activities? Common sense tells me that something like 3 hours a week is enough, otherwise there won't be any free/family time. Is there any known rule of thumb or studies? Or, in a nutshell, could it be anything, depending on the child?

Comment: Is your 4 year old in school yet?  All day/half day/intermittent preschool?

Comment: She is going to be in a childcare in about 9 to 16 daily

Answer (score 1):

> Or, in a nutshell, it could be anything depending on a child?

In my, non-scientific, experience it very much depends on the child.

My 4yo has enough energy to spare to do three hours of sports a week besides school.

On the other hand, school also facilitates 4yo children who can't manage to go to school for full days without falling asleep.